# Multiple Output of Anonymous Function (Function Handler) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, lambda, anonymous-function

I have a function "myFunction" that computes the value and the gradient of a certain quantity. I want to maximize this quantity; since I will use fmincon, I want to pass to fmincon -myFunction. The issue is that myFunction returns also the gradient, i.e. it should be used as

```
valueFunction, gradientFunction = myFunction(point)
```

And gradientFunction will be used by fmincon to compute the minimum. So what I would like to have is have a function that returns -valueFunction, -gradientFunction. But if I define

```
k=@(x) -myFunction(x)
```

matlab raises the error

```
Error using - 
Too many output arguments
```

So how to create a function that returns all the outputs of another function, with the opposite sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since negating a function is equivalent to multiply is by -1 you should also negate the function which calculates the gradient.

Now, you real problem is that you need to output 2 variables for a function handler.

You can do something as described in here - [Multiple Outputs](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/01/31/multiple-outputs/).

Another option is to create a new function - `NegateMyFunction()`:

```
function [valueFunction, gradientFunction] = NegateMyFunction( x )

valueFunction, gradientFunction = myFunction(x);
valueFunction = -valueFunction;
gradientFunction = -gradientFunction;

end
```

Use that for `fmincon`.

Comment: It is the function myFunction that returns the value and the gradient (it returns both outputs); I don't have two different functions. The gradient used in fmincon is the one supplied by myFunction, I don't make matlab compute it with finite differences (which would be too slow). I have edited my question to make it more clear :)

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the cleanest solution.